# Jquery tree and asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, jquery, tree

I have few specific questions on how to make these two work.
I need the tree that can be manipulated on the client side (add/delete nodes, expand/collapse) and that can be saved in the database when the user specifically presses a SAVE button.

From the research I have done, I gather that what I need to do is use a callback (asp.net callback) to consume the jquery tree when the Save button is pressed and send it to the server. I would be interested to know if anyone has any experience dealing with this scenario.

Do I send it back to the server in Javascript array, JSON or XML? 
I have a simple example worked out with callback where my page is defined as following in my aspx.cs file:

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page, ICallbackEventHandler
```

(I would post the code but for some reason, when I try to post a big chunk the formatting is screwed up)

Now, I am wondering what are the technicalities here, what is the difference between CallBack and asp.net ajax library. From what I read, it is essentially the same.

So should I be able to consume a Javascript tree and package it up and then send it to the server for saving into DB?

I am using asp.net webforms

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier solution. Create your Jquery treeview, then wireup an HTML submit button to fire an AJAX call from JQuery ($.Ajax(function(){}.....) and send it to a web service (*.asmx) that will handle the callback. Here is a sample that explains it:

[example here](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)